# wget: how to exclude subdomains other than some knowns?

Tags: wget, gnu

### The first question is, for example:

> I want to download files from a top level domain(e.g. `https://example.com/`) with including resources from a subdomain(e.g. `abc.example.com`), but not from other subdomains, which are not certain.

I found that the `--domain` option doesn't performs an exact match. so <strike>`wget --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --domains=example.com,abc.expample.com https://example.com/`</strike> is not working.

What's more, `--domains` and `--exclude-domains` have no priority on order. So <strike>`--exclude-domains .example.com --domains=example.com,abc.example.com`</strike> is also not as expected.

> So, the first question is how to `wget` including top level domain and specific subdomain(s), but not other subdomains?

---

### There is also another question:

> Can I write a `wget` command line, with `--span-host` option only for assets files (js/css/image etc. but not document)?

Answer (score 0):

> I found that the --domain option doesn't performs an exact match. so
> wget --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites
> --domains=example.com,abc.expample.com https://example.com/ is not working.

You have to turn the `--span-hosts` flag on for the `--domains` option to work.

So, the correct command would be:

```
wget --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --span-hosts --domains=example.com,abc.expample.com https://example.com/
```